# flock permission denied bash

Tags: bash, permissions, flock

I have written a little test script to prevent running my script simultaneously with flock:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptname=$(basename $0)
lock="/var/run/${scriptname}"
umask 0002

exec 200>$lock
flock -n 200 || exit 1

## The code:
sleep 60
echo "Hello world"
```

When I run the script with my user and try to run the script with another user I got following error message with the lock file.

```
/var/run/test.lock: Permission denied
```

Any idea?

Kind regards,
Andreas

Comment: You said: "When I run the script with my user and try to run the script with another user": question, are you running both simultaneously ? Or problem is even after execution finished after your user ran, and some other tries to run, this error appears?

Comment: What's the group of the file ? Does the second user is in that group ?

Comment: The script runs as user1 and i got the error message when i run it simultanesouly with user2.

Comment: other user is in the same group. file permissions are -rw-r--r--

Comment: aren't you stopping in your script i.e. to run it simultaneously by two user?
I guess you are using flock for that? 
Now I have to ask you, what happens when user1 run it , and user2 run it after 60 seconds i.e. user1's instance finishes?>??????? Does it run without issues >?

Answer (score 5):

In a comment, you mention that

> other user is in the same group. file permissions are `-rw-r--r--`

In other words, only the first user has *write* permissions on the lock file.

However, your script does:

```
exec 200>$lock
```

which attempts to open the lockfile for *writing*. Hence the "permission denied" error.

Opening the file for writing has the advantage that it won't fail if the file doesn't exist, but it also means that you can't easily predict who the owner of the file will be if your script is being run simultaneously by more than one user. [1]

In most linux distributions, the `umask` will be set to `0022`, which causes newly-created files to have permissions `rw-r--r--`, which means that only the user which creates the file will have write permissions. That's sane security policy but it complicates using a lockfile shared between two or more users. If the users are in the same group, you could adjust your umask so that new files are created with group write permissions, remembering to set it back afterwards. For example (untested):

```
OLD_UMASK=$(umask)
umask 002
exec 200>"$lock"
umask $OLD_UMASK
```

Alternatively, you could apply the lock with only read permissions [2], taking care to ensure that the file is created first:

```
touch "$lock" 2>/dev/null # Don't care if it fails.
exec 200<"$lock"          # Note: < instead of >
```

---

**Notes:**

[1]: Another issue with `exec 200>file` is that it will truncate the file if it *does* exist, so it is only appropriate for empty files. In general, you should use `>>` unless you know for certain that the file contains no useful information.

[2]: `flock` doesn't care what mode the file is open in. See `man 1 flock` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to use flock on a file with shared group permissions with a system account. Access permissions changed in Ubuntu 19.10 due to an updated kernel. You must be logged in as the user who owns the file, and not a user whose group matches the file permissions. Even sudo -u  will show 'permission denied' or 'This account is currently not available'. It affects fifo files like the ones used by the flock command.

[The reason for the change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5) is due to security vulnerabilities.

[There is a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875667) to get the older behaviour back in:

> create `/etc/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf` with the contents:
>
> fs.protected_regular = 0
>
> Then restart procps:
>
> sudo systemctl restart procps.service

Answer (score 0):

Run the whole script by `sudo /path/script.sh` instead of only `/path/script.sh`

Comment: or run the whole script by `sudo /path/script.sh`

Comment: with `sudo /path/script.sh` it works, but I would handle it better inside the script and then when I write `lock="sudo /var/run/${scriptname}"` I got following error:
`$lock: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: run your script by `sudo /path/script.sh` command. Don't change anything inside the script.